# Date Insertion Problem

Tags: apex, soap-api, webservices

I develop a webservice i am getting the date 12/9/2013 format while i am inserting this date in opportunity object but the date which comes from thirdparty system is not inserting exactly.

my code is for date insert.

```
Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
o.Name = rName; // rName Which Coming from Third Party system
o.CloseDate = ocDate; // when i map like this means it not taking may i know i want to da any modifications the date which was given by third party system that data must be insert in sfdc
insert o;
```

Comment: debug and find what is format of  ocDate from the webservice ?

Comment: The format of ocdate is   webservice Date ocDate;

Comment: What do you mean by is not inserting exactly? What is the error?. If I understand correctly, the date format you are receiving is not the one salesforce is expecting, you will need to manipulate it before inserting if that is the case.

Comment: suppose if i get date 9/12/2013 that same date have to insert in sfdc, that whatever date comes from thirdpary system that date have to insert into sfdc.for me not inserting may i know i have do any modifications in date

Comment: @Sathya Still you are not specific here .Please be crystal clear .put some logs and check the issue

Comment: Is that really your code? You're inserting 0 (the number zero), not o.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     Try this code

    String[] str = ocDate.split(' ');
    String[] dts = str[0].split('/');

    Date myDate = date.newinstance(Integer.valueOf(dts[2]), Integer.valueOf(dts[0]), Integer.valueOf(dts[1]));

o.CloseDate = myDate;
insert o;
```

date.newinstance(year,month,date) format

Refer the link
[link](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/convert-a-string-of-datetime-into-date-in-apex-class/td-p/593991)

Comment: It's working for me thanq for giving response.

Comment: hello @sathya, if its working fro you then you should upvote the answer and accept the answer.  This will bring visibility to the question and help other members of the community with similar question